# Evaluate tan(x +y), and determine the quadrant it is located in.

Tags: functions, trigonometry

If $x$ is in Q1 and $y$ is in Q2, $\sin x = \frac{24}{25}$ and $\sin y = \frac45$, evaluate $\tan(x + y)$, and determine the quadrant in which $x + y$ is located.

Comment: yeah oops, I'll edit that.

Comment: To get you started if $\sin x = \frac {24}{25}$ what is $\cos x$ and $\tan x$?  If $y$ is in Q2 what is the sign of $\cos y,\tan y$?  What is the angle addition rule for $\tan(x+y)$?  If you don't know it, (and I do not recommend memorizing it for its own sake) what is $\frac {\sin (x+y)}{\cos(x+y)}$  what is the sign of $\tan(x+y)$ and what does that imply regarding quadrants?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: 
One has
$$\tan^2 \theta=\frac{\sin^2 \theta}{1-\sin^2 \theta},$$
 from which you can deduce $\tan x$ and $\tan y$, determining their signs from the quadrant $x$ and $y$ belong to. Then apply the addition formula for the tangent.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

We have that by $\sin^2 \theta + \cos^2 \theta =1$

- $\sin x =\frac{24}{25} \implies \cos x =\frac{7}{25}$
- $\sin y =\frac{4}{5} \implies \cos y =-\frac{3}{5}$

then use

$$\tan(x+y)=\frac{\tan x + \tan y}{1-\tan x \tan y}$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: use
$$\tan (x+y) = \frac{\tan x+\tan y}{1-\tan x\tan y}.$$
Since $0\leq x \leq \pi/2$, then $\cos x = \sqrt{1-\sin^2x}$ and you have $\cos x = \sqrt{1-576/625} = 7/25$. Then $\tan x = \frac{24/25}{7/25} = 24/7$. Try to find $\tan y$ with a similar method.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a homework problem.

Recognize the Pythagorean triples and use properties of $\sin$ and $\cos$ to get $\cos x = \frac{7}{25}$ and $\cos y = -\frac{3}{5}$.  Thus, $\tan x = \frac{24}{7}$ and $\tan y = -\frac{4}{3}$.  Now use the trigonometric identity

$\tan(x+y) = \frac{\tan x + \tan y}{1 - \tan x \tan y}$.

This tells us that

$\tan(x+y) = \frac{\frac{24}{7} - \frac{4}{3}}{1 + \frac{24}{7}\frac{4}{3}} = \frac{44}{117}$.

Angle $x+y$ lies in quadrant $3$ by use of inverse trigonometric functions.

Comment: thanks, but since tan (x + y ) turned out to be positive, how do I determine whether it's in Q1 or Q3?

Comment: From the hypotheses we know that $0 < x < \frac{\pi}{2}$ and $\frac{\pi}{2} < y < \pi$, so  $x+y$ is in Q2 or Q3.  Since $\tan(x+y)$ is positive, we know that $x+y$ is in Q3 instead of Q2.